# Confidence Intervals Overlaping Although Significant Effects in glmer in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

Below is the output of a glmer:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Gamma  ( log )
Formula: FrameDelay ~ Group + Session + Group:Session + cs.Age + cs.Years +      Group:cs.Years + (1 | PID)
   Data: ufov

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 205033.6  205149.0 -102501.8  205003.6     16297 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8549  0.0144  0.1596  0.3123  5.8694 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 PID      (Intercept) 0.005684 0.07539 
 Residual             0.061994 0.24899 
Number of obs: 16312, groups:  PID, 81

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            6.042558   0.029594 204.181  < 2e-16 ***
Group1                -0.147880   0.051494  -2.872  0.00408 ** 
Group2                -0.040637   0.047366  -0.858  0.39094    
Group3                 0.060889   0.052523   1.159  0.24634    
Session6-month        -0.013312   0.005221  -2.550  0.01078 *  
cs.Age                 0.086955   0.029522   2.945  0.00322 ** 
cs.Years              -0.044833   0.029957  -1.497  0.13450    
Group1:Session6-month  0.043462   0.009249   4.699 2.61e-06 ***
Group2:Session6-month -0.029628   0.008414  -3.521  0.00043 ***
Group3:Session6-month  0.014595   0.009024   1.617  0.10581    
Group1:cs.Years        0.048266   0.054528   0.885  0.37608    
Group2:cs.Years       -0.078277   0.052164  -1.501  0.13346    
Group3:cs.Years        0.037308   0.050069   0.745  0.45619    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here is the emmeans:

```
$emmeans
Group = Advanced:
 Session  emmean     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Baseline   5.89 0.0595 Inf      5.76      6.03
 6-month    5.92 0.0594 Inf      5.79      6.06

Group = Aerobic:
 Session  emmean     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Baseline   6.00 0.0521 Inf      5.88      6.12
 6-month    5.96 0.0520 Inf      5.84      6.07

Group = Inactive:
 Session  emmean     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Baseline   6.10 0.0613 Inf      5.96      6.24
 6-month    6.10 0.0613 Inf      5.97      6.24

Group = Novice:
 Session  emmean     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Baseline   6.17 0.0634 Inf      6.03      6.31
 6-month    6.13 0.0633 Inf      5.99      6.27

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 2 estimates 

$contrasts
Group = Advanced:
 contrast           estimate      SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Baseline - 6-month -0.03015 0.01080 Inf -2.793  0.0052 **

Group = Aerobic:
 contrast           estimate      SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Baseline - 6-month  0.04294 0.00933 Inf  4.602  <.0001 **

Group = Inactive:
 contrast           estimate      SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Baseline - 6-month -0.00128 0.01041 Inf -0.123  0.9019 

Group = Novice:
 contrast           estimate      SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Baseline - 6-month  0.04174 0.01114 Inf  3.746  0.0002 **

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

Notice there are 3 pairwise comparisons that are significant. However, the error bars (95% confidence intervals) overlap for the Advanced, Aerobic, and Novice when those are the significant effects.

```
data <- data.frame(Effect(c("Group", "Session"), ufov9)) 
data$lower_bound <- data$fit - (1.96*data$se)
data$upper_bound <- data$fit + (1.96*data$se)
```

[image: dataframe with fit, se, and UCI and LCI]

```
ggplot(aes(y = fit, x =Session,  group = Group, ymin = lower_bound, ymax = upper_bound), data = data) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Group, color = Group)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Group, color = Group), fill = "white", size = 4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_bound, ymax = upper_bound, color = Group), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) + 
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 18 ) + 
  labs(y = "Processing Speed (ms)", x = "Testing Session")+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  facet_grid(. ~Group)
```

[image: Graph from the code above, showing overlapping error bars]

I saw in a previous post that said means and difference of means are different and should not be compared, however I cannot find any other literature or resource on this matter to explain this in my write-up.

Do I remove the error bars in the results or do I keep them? Is this normal for glmer effects to have large error bars that overlap?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not positive, but I think what is happening is that your plot (and the data behind it) are not treating the data as paired.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by paired? Do you have any resources I could look at about your comment?

Comment: Paired meaning that the same people are measured twice, so they are paired. If you Google "paired t test" you will find a lot. (I know you didn't do a ttest, but the principles are the same).

Comment: So in other words, it would be more appropriate to plot one bar for each group showing the difference from Baseline to 6-months?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to the question of using the right tool for the job. Consider these two statistical calculations:

1. Confidence intervals for the means $M_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$
2. Tests of the differences $M_i-M_j$ for $i\ne j$

The point I want to make as clearly as possible is that the $M_i$ and the $M_i-M_j$ are *very different* statistical quantities, and it is a serious mistake to confuse them. In particular, the sampling distributions of these may have very different variances, and this is especially true with mixed models. Consider a situation with paired data, for example. The variance of the means $M_i$ *include* the variations among subjects, while that variance disappears in the $M_i-M_j$ because the observations are on the same subjects and the subject effects cancel out. So, often, the variance of the $M_i-M_j$ is very much smaller than the variance of the $M_i$. The opposite is true with independent samples, where the variance of the $M_i-M_j$ is double that of the variance of the $M_i$. In both cases, tests of differences will differ from results obtained by overlapping confidence intervals.

The bottom line is this: You should *never, ever* test differences by seeing whether confidence intervals for the means overlap. As tempting as it is, just don't do it. It is conflating two different sampling distributions for two different sets of statistics.

To show comparisons graphically, you can

- obtain confidence intervals for the $M_i-M_j$ themselves and graph them; or
- use software designed to display comparisons. The **emmeans** package offers "comparison arrows" via `plot(..., comparisons = TRUE)` (but they don't always work), and the `pwpp()` function.